# Weird User Request in access log

Tags: php, forms, request, lighttpd, access-log

I'm evaluating the AccessLog of our reverse proxy here and I came accross some weird user requests.

Th normal request would be, that the user requests a page with a form on it via GET Request:
`XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX www.example.de - [25/Jul/2023:07:31:01 +0200] GET /routetoform/ HTTP/1.1" 200 T ORIGIN "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 16_5 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) EdgiOS/114.0.1823.82 Version/16.0 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1"`

And then when the user submits the form:
`XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX www.example.de - [25/Jul/2023:07:33:11 +0200] "POST /routetoform/ HTTP/1.1" 200 T ORIGIN "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 16_5 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) EdgiOS/114.0.1823.82 Version/16.0 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1"`

What I find are a lot of request that do START with the second line, the POST Request, without having the first line.
So the users START with sending the form, without even seeing it.

The user agent is always an iPhone Safari:
`Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 16_5 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) EdgiOS/114.0.1823.82 Version/16.0 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1`

My thought was then "Hey, maybe, the user device got a new IP, right before the POST Request. So I search via User Agent, but I can't find another entry.

So, the user REALLY just popped into the POST Request.

I tried to find something about this behaviour in the net, but wasn't very successful.

Does any of have any idea what might cause this?
The user agent doesn't really point to a bot and how the hell can someone enter a page with an "I just submitted the form"-Request?

Comment: This can be a sign that someone is using a robot to get information from your site, or even try to hack it. You didn't tell use what information can be retrieved with the post, but I guess someone, or something, would only do this if it can be beneficial to them. An easy method to protect against this is to add something to the form submit, like a token, that cannot be easily replicated. When the token is absent, or it's not the right one, the POST request is not processed.

Comment: Analysing the POST payload for these requests would perhaps tell you more of the nature of the unsolicited POST requests

Comment: Could be a [CSRF attack](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/csrf). There are a lot of info out there on how to protect against it, if you haven't done that already. It's just "one of those things" you always should have in place, just like protecting against XSS attacks. Basically, there's nothing special about a browser. It's just a client making requests to your server. Anyone can make a request to your server in _many_ different ways. And any endpoint your form submits to can be accessed directly. You need to verify that it's a valid request (from the form) on your side (the backend)

Comment: _"The user agent doesn't really point to a bot"_ - well that's what a bot with malicious intentions would usually try to avoid.

Comment: Thank you all!
The form is just for unsubscribtion from info mails. So the only thing, that could really harm is a bot unsubscribtion with real data, but that isn't the case.

Comment: So nothing really to worry about. Although I would do something about bots potentially being able to unsubscribe people. Basically any form submission page needs proper protection against abuse.